# ActiveStorage & S3: Make files public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

In my `rails` application, some images should be `public` and others should be `private`. (I don't mind to have all of them public).

Currently, when calling ActiveStorage's `service_url` (when using `s3`), a new `presigned` url is being generated. I totally understand this, but it's not what I want to do.

Right now, generating the `presigned` url is taking too much time:

---

### Example:

Getting 10 records:

- ActiveRecord: 52.3ms
- Generating the JSON: 1,790ms

If we dig deeper, we see the following:

- `S3 Storage (23.9ms) Checked if file exists at key: variants/p5Enur12ZMUEgMb6niJDtS2W/6cb99d2f2eca3bafc444d3c7cdfab34cd303f2578891852655d60028981c8950 (yes)`
- `S3 Storage (3.2ms) Generated URL for file at key: variants/p5Enur12ZMUEgMb6niJDtS2W/6cb99d2f2eca3bafc444d3c7cdfab34cd303f2578891852655d60028981c8950`

In my example, I'm getting 10 `Match`es, where each `Match` has `teams` and `competition`. `Team` and `Competition` have one image.

I'm also generating the following JSON Structure:

```
{
  ...
  image: {
    original: ...,
    thumbnail: ...,
    medium: ...,
    large: ...,
  }
}
```

With this taken into consideration, here are the numbers:

- 10 matches * ( 1 team + 1 competition ) = `20` images
- each image has `4` sizes
- each size takes around `27ms`
- --> 20 * 4 * 27 = `~2,160ms`

---

Is there a way to make all the uploaded files public and we'll have the `2,160ms` completely removed ?

### ---

### Edit: answer

```
def url_for_file(file:, size: nil, process: false)
  s3_storage = Rails.application.config.active_storage.service == :amazon

  if size.nil?
    url = file
  else
    url = file.variant(size)

    if process
      url = url.processed
    end
  end

  if s3_storage
    amazon_config = Rails.application.config.active_storage.service_configurations.amazon
    return "https://s3.#{amazon_config.region}.amazonaws.com/#{amazon_config.bucket}/#{url.key}"
  else
    return url.service_url
  end
end
```

With this small hack, you will only `process` the files when you want ( and assume they are processed when presenting ), also, won't call `.service_url` which checks if the file exists.
This is only valid if your `acl` config is `public`.

Comment: Whether or not the attachment is private or public is, from what I can tell, irrelevant. The key is used to uniquely identify attachments/variants. The access level is on the service (S3) level, not the Rails level. Maybe caching will help?

Comment: @MarkMerritt I thought of caching the hash; but this might grow a lot since the users also have images and other models too. I was thinking if there’s any other way to do it without caching.. thanks for the comment though:-)

Comment: I have the exact same concerns about performance with a public website with many images... I think that you can call `service_url` (without `processed`) on the variant and avoid the expensive redirect. In this case you will have to call `processed` at least once on each image (e.g. in a background job) when you upload it

Comment: @collimarco that works only for not re-uploading the assets; however, it still generates the assets. This cuts the request by half, but still takes some extra time (~ 1,200ms). Thanks for the recommendation though :-)

Comment: @RocKhalil did you find any solution?

Comment: @Cap I didn't look at it after this thread. It was a quick project using ActiveStorage for testing purposes. All my other projects are with `paperclip`. If I re-work on this in the near future, I'll post the solution when I find it :-)

Comment: @collimarco I've updating the question to have right answer for it. This really saved us a lot of processing time which we didn't need to. APIs are now way faster.

Comment: @Cap ^ + check the edits